# DevTools failed to load source map

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome, twilio

I'm aware of many posts regarding these warnings in Chrome dev tools. For all of them, the solution is to turn off notifications "Enable javascript source maps" and "Enable CSS source maps".

What I want to know is **how to FIX this** and what is the reason under the hood that causes these warnings.

I'm currently developing a Vue JS app that uses [Twilio Js SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/javascript)
and I'm getting tons of warnings when the app is built in stage mode by using `sudo npm run build -- --mode staging`

Any advice will be appreciated.

```
ls failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/perfect-scrollbar/dist/perfect-scrollbar.esm.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/pusher-js/dist/web/utf8.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/index.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/preflight/preflighttest.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/util/constants.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/preflight/timer.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/preflight/mos.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/preflight/getCombinedConnectionStats.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/preflight/getturncredentials.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/twilioconnection.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/statemachine.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/util/index.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/util/sid.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/util/log.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/vendor/loglevel.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/util/networkmonitor.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/util/timeout.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/preflight/makestat.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/preflight/syntheticaudio.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/preflight/syntheticvideo.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/util/movingaveragedelta.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/util/eventobserver.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/util/insightspublisher/index.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/connect.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/cancelableroompromise.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/util/cancelablepromise.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/createlocaltracks.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/media/track/es5/localaudiotrack.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/media/track/localaudiotrack.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/media/track/audiotrack.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/media/track/mediatrack.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/util/localmediarestartdeferreds.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/media/track/index.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/media/track/localmediatrack.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/util/detectsilentaudio.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/webaudio/detectsilence.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/util/detectsilentvideo.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/util/documentvisibilitymonitor.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/webaudio/workaround180748.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/media/track/sender.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/media/track/transceiver.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/transceiver.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/media/track/es5/localvideotrack.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/media/track/localvideotrack.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/media/track/videotrack.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/media/track/videoprocessoreventobserver.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/media/track/es5/localdatatrack.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/media/track/localdatatrack.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/data/sender.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/data/transceiver.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/encodingparameters.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/localparticipant.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/util/validate.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/media/track/localaudiotrackpublication.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/media/track/localtrackpublication.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/media/track/trackpublication.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/media/track/localdatatrackpublication.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/media/track/localvideotrackpublication.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/participant.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/media/track/remoteaudiotrack.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/media/track/remotemediatrack.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/media/track/remoteaudiotrackpublication.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/media/track/remotetrackpublication.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/media/track/remotedatatrack.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/media/track/remotedatatrackpublication.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/media/track/remotevideotrack.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/util/nullobserver.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/media/track/remotevideotrackpublication.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/util/insightspublisher/null.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/networkqualityconfiguration.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/room.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/remoteparticipant.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/stats/statsreport.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/stats/localaudiotrackstats.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/stats/localtrackstats.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/stats/trackstats.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/stats/localvideotrackstats.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/stats/remoteaudiotrackstats.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/stats/remotetrackstats.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/stats/remotevideotrackstats.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/signaling/v2/index.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/signaling/v2/cancelableroomsignalingpromise.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/signaling/v2/peerconnectionmanager.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/signaling/v2/peerconnection.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/util/sdp/index.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/util/sdp/simulcast.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/util/twilio-video-errors.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/util/twilioerror.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/signaling/v2/icebox.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/util/filter.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/signaling/v2/iceconnectionmonitor.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/data/receiver.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/data/transport.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/media/track/receiver.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/util/sdp/trackmatcher/identity.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/util/sdp/trackmatcher/ordered.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/util/sdp/trackmatcher/mid.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/util/sdp/issue8329.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/queueingeventemitter.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/signaling/v2/room.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/signaling/v2/dominantspeakersignaling.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/signaling/v2/mediasignaling.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/signaling/v2/networkqualitymonitor.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/stats/peerconnectionreportfactory.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/stats/icereportfactory.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/stats/icereport.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/stats/peerconnectionreport.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/stats/receiverreport.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/stats/average.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/stats/senderorreceiverreport.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/stats/sum.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/stats/senderreport.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/stats/receiverreportfactory.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/stats/senderorreceiverreportfactory.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/stats/senderreportfactory.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/signaling/v2/networkqualitysignaling.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/util/asyncvar.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/signaling/v2/recording.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/signaling/recording.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/signaling/room.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/signaling/v2/remoteparticipant.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/signaling/remoteparticipant.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/signaling/participant.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/stats/networkqualitystats.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/stats/networkqualityaudiostats.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/stats/networkqualitymediastats.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/stats/networkqualitysendstats.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/stats/networkqualitysendorrecvstats.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/stats/networkqualitybandwidthstats.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/stats/networkqualityfractionloststats.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/stats/networkqualitylatencystats.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/stats/networkqualityrecvstats.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/stats/networkqualityvideostats.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/signaling/v2/remotetrackpublication.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/signaling/remotetrackpublication.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/signaling/track.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/signaling/v2/trackprioritysignaling.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/signaling/v2/trackswitchoffsignaling.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/signaling/v2/renderhintssignaling.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/signaling/v2/publisherhintsignaling.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/signaling/v2/twilioconnectiontransport.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/signaling/v2/localparticipant.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/signaling/localparticipant.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/signaling/v2/localtrackpublication.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/signaling/localtrackpublication.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/signaling/index.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/createlocaltrack.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/twilio-video/es5/util/support.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Do you need to turn on sourcemaps in webpack, like in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1806)?

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: {
        devtool: 'source-map'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! No more warnings now. Taking advantage of your Twilio's knowledge I've posted a question about it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71003081/twilio-remaining-participant-is-disconnected-when-gets-alone

Comment: In my case this was set as a parameter in my package.json