# Twilio remaining participant is disconnected when gets alone

Tags: vue.js, twilio-api, twilio-php

I've already posted an issue in the official git repository but no answers so far.
https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video.js/issues/1698

I'm creating a Twilio programmable video Go room by using the PHP API.
Then participants connect to the room from a Vue Js App (using JS SDK) or from android (using Andoird SDK)

When one of them faces a network error, after a minute it gets disconnected from the room. Immediately after that, the remaining participant gets disconnected.

I'm wondering if this is the expected behavior of twilio. Once both joined the room, if one of them lose the room connection, the other one should be disconnected?

This is the log I get from the first participant joining the room
http://pastie.org/p/6fQtbykhRgACM9606mkgRN

```
<template>
    <div>        
        <div id="localTrack"></div>
        <div id="remoteTrack"></div>

        <b-btn @click="doConnect">Start call</b-btn>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { connect, createLocalVideoTrack, createLocalAudioTrack } from 'twilio-video'
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
    name: 'Video',

    data: () => ({
        participants: [],
        activeRoom: null,

        localAudioTrack: {},
        localVideoTrack: {}
    }),

    mounted () {
        this.initLocalMedia()

        if (this.activeRoom?.participants?.size) {
            this.activeRoom.participants.forEach(this.participantConnected)
        }
    },

    computed: {
        ...mapState({
            twilioToken: state => state.call.twilioToken,
            call: state => state.call,
            room: state => state.call.room
        })
    },

    methods: {
        async initLocalMedia () {
            await createLocalVideoTrack({ width: 350 }).then(track => {
                const localMediaContainer = document.getElementById('localTrack')
                localMediaContainer.appendChild(track.attach())

                this.localVideoTrack = track
            }).catch(e => { this.videoError = e.message })

            await createLocalAudioTrack().then(track => {
                this.localAudioTrack = track
            }).catch(e => { this.audioError = e.message })
        },

        async doConnect () {
            // console.log('connect')

            const tracks = []
            if (this.localVideoTrack.id) tracks.push(this.localVideoTrack)
            if (this.localAudioTrack.id) tracks.push(this.localAudioTrack)

            const connectOptions = {
                name: this.room.name,
                audio: true,
                video: { width: 400 },
                tracks: tracks,
                logLevel: 'debug'
            }

            const twilioToken = this.call.twilioToken

            // remove any remote track when connecting a new room
            document.getElementById('remoteTrack').innerHTML = ''

            const VueThis = this
            await connect(twilioToken, connectOptions).then(function (room) {
                // set active room
                VueThis.activeRoom = room

                room.participants.forEach(VueThis.participantConnected)
                room.on('participantConnected', VueThis.participantConnected)
                room.on('participantDisconnected', VueThis.participantDisconnected)
                room.once('disconnected', async () => {
                    room.participants.forEach(VueThis.participantDisconnected)
                })
            })
        },

        async disconnect () {
            // console.log('disconnect')
            if (this.activeRoom) {
                await this.activeRoom.disconnect()
            }
            this.activeRoom = null
            this.hudHidden = false
        },

        participantConnected (participant) {
            this.participants.push(participant)

            const remoteMediaContainer = document.getElementById('remoteTrack')
            const div = document.createElement('div')
            div.id = participant.sid

            participant.on('trackSubscribed', track => this.trackSubscribed(div, track))
            participant.on('trackUnsubscribed', this.trackUnsubscribed)

            remoteMediaContainer.appendChild(div)

            participant.tracks.forEach(publication => {
                if (publication.isSubscribed) {
                    this.trackSubscribed(div, publication.track)
                }
            })

            this.primaryVideoLocal = false
        },

        participantDisconnected (participant) {
            this.participants = this.participants.filter(item => item.identity !== participant.identity)

            if (this.activeRoom.participants?.size === 0) this.showRemote = false
            if (document.getElementById(participant.sid)) document.getElementById(participant.sid).remove()
        },

        trackSubscribed (div, track) {
            div.appendChild(track.attach())
        },

        trackUnsubscribed (track) {
            track.detach().forEach(element => element.remove())
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: When a remote participant disconnects from a Go room, it is not expected that the local participant also disconnects. Is there anything your application might be doing on participant disconnect that is causing this? Can you share your code? Particularly around participant disconnection events?

Comment: Not at all, I actually removed the `room.on('participantDisconnected', ...)` and `room.once('disconnected', ...)` from within `connect()` method, so nothing is triggered when disconnection is done because I have no listeners defined. I've updated my question with relevant code

Comment: I’m not very experienced with Vue, but I notice that you are removing elements from the DOM using DOM methods. In my experience with React that doesn’t tend to work well with the framework. Is there a chance that when you receive the unsubscribed event and you remove the element it causes the component to rerender and that ends the call?

Comment: Did you find the reason for this? We are seeing similar behavior in our app

Comment: @Mertus no, we had to change how our internal flow on participant disconnection. Since we keep track of rooms in our API, on participant disconnection we are reverting our call session status to a previous step, so after a minute, when both get disconnected, the user who starts the call must manually start it again.